Find count of rows having a text on multiple columns. Need an alias row to display
I have a table with multiple columns.’Product Name’ being one. Table has records for multiple products. product name is also used in a free text field. I need reports on how many rows have a particular product listed in ‘Product Name’or in ‘Free text’ fields.
Table as below :



Product Name
Issue description




Microsoft
outlook not working


Lenovo
laptop blue screen


Samsung
microsoft word issu



I need the results as below :



Product
number of records




Microsoft
2 ( one for outlook issue and other for word issue on a different product)



I need the product ( could be an alias), but need ‘Microsoft’ in the results
Is this achievable ?
I tried sub queries using ‘WITH’ and AS. Doesn’t work.
I’m using a reporting tool with freehand sql. Could not achieve with sub-queries. Appreciate any guidance.

Can you share the complete table definition and the actual queries you tried, along with their results?

You can achieve this using a UNION to combine results from both the Product Name and the Issue Description columns. Here’s a SQL query that should work for your case:
SELECT 'Microsoft' AS Product, COUNT(*) AS number_of_records
FROM (
   SELECT "Product Name"
   FROM your_table
   WHERE "Product Name" = 'Microsoft'
   
   UNION ALL
   
   SELECT "Issue description"
   FROM your_table
   WHERE "Issue description" LIKE '%Microsoft%'
) AS combined_results


What can be done for multiple products. If I need the report for Microsoft and Lenovo.

Was able to do it with case statement.thank you very much

SELECT 
    product_name,
    COUNT(issue) AS issue_count,
    CONCAT(COUNT(issue), ' (', STRING_AGG(issue, ' and '), ')') AS number_of_records
FROM 
    product
GROUP BY 
    product_name;


By using STRING_AGG function combined with a GROUP BY clause to group the issues by the product name and concatenate them if there are multiple issues for the same product.

